Creating a cumulative frequency table with custom row ordering in R
I have an R function which returns a cumulative frequency table, however the row values are qualitative data and I need them in a certain order.
tab_1 <- function(dataset, var){
 dataset %>%
    group_by({{var}}) %>% 
    summarise(n=n()) %>%
    mutate(totalN = cumsum(n),
           percent = n / sum(n)*100,
           cumpercent = cumsum(n / sum(n)*100))

The values for my variable in the order I would like are in a text format as follows
None
0 < x < 5
5 < x < 10
10 < x < 20
More than 20
However the function above returns a table in the order



var
frequency




0 < x < 5
2


5 < x < 10
5


10 < x < 20
5


More than 20
10


None
30



I've tried using order and c "none", "0 < x < 5" etc but I just can't quite get it to work.

Can you share some code? You say the function above but you haven't showed us what the function is. Generally, you probably want to look at making var a factor() and using the levels argument to set the order.

Turn var into a factor and specify its levels by hand: factor(var, levels = c("None", "0 < x < 5", ...)).

Your toy labels are badly chosen, 5, 10, 20 are excluded.

Sorry I thought I posted the code but something must have glitched: tab_1 <- function(dataset, var){
dataset %>%
group_by({{var}}) %>%
summarise(n=n()) %>%
mutate(totalN = cumsum(n),
percent = n / sum(n)*100,
cumpercent = cumsum(n / sum(n)*100))

You might want cut + table. Set breaks and create labels according to your needs (programmatically).
x = c(18, 29, 17, 20, 14, 2, 27, 20, 18, 30, 16, 12, 17, 10, 29, 7, 18, 21, 0, 37, 10, 28, 10, 29, 18)
l = c("None", "0<x<5", "5<x<10", "10<x<20", "20 and more") 
table(cut(x, breaks = c(0, 4, 9, 14, 19, Inf), labels = l)) |> as.data.frame()


         Var1 Freq
1        None    1
2       0<x<5    1
3      5<x<10    5
4     10<x<20    7
5 20 and more   10

